# Password Encryption in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

We can do password encryption in C#/VB. Is there any mechanism to **`encrypt the Password in SQL Server?`** I want to generate encrypted password and send mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `HASHBYTES()`

**Example:**

```
--HASHBYTES ( '<algorithm>', { @input | 'input' } ) 
--<algorithm>::= MD2 | MD2 | MD5 | SHA | SHA1 | SHA2_256 | SHA2_512 

DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(4000);
SELECT @HashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),'demo');
SELECT HashBytes('MD2', @HashThis);
SELECT HashBytes('MD5', @HashThis);
SELECT HashBytes('SHA', @HashThis);
SELECT HashBytes('SHA1', @HashThis);
```

For more detailed study, please refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms174415.aspx)

**EDIT**: But i think it wont fulfill your last requirement of 'sending mail to user' n all. Still you can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using DB specific stuff, you may want to consider using the BouncyCastle library to encrypt the passwords.